# Why can't I set the value of a select option with my URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of a select option by the url parameters associated with the select. I am able to hard code the value of the parameters without issue, if I try to programmatically set the value via javascript, the options don't get selected.

Assume the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?date_range=ytd&treatments=%5B"1"%2C"15"%5D
```

My select:

```
<select id="dashboardTreatmentSelector" class="js-example-basic-multiple- form-control" name="treatments[]" multiple="multiple">
<option></option>
<option id="1" data-id="1" value="1">dsfrets</option>
<option id="2" data-id="2" value="2">Aphid Treatment</option>
<option id="15" data-id="15" value="15">boom pow surprise</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following to get the value of the url parameters:

```
$.urlParam = function (name) {
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.search);

return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}
```

The values are getting set using the following:

```
function setValuesBasedOnParams(){
var date_range = $.urlParam('date_range');
var treatments = $.urlParam('treatments');

if(date_range){
    $(".btn_dateRangeSelector").removeClass("btn-primary");
    $("#daterange_"+date_range).addClass("btn-primary");
}
if(treatments){
    var t = decodeURIComponent(treatments);
    var treatments_value = t.replace(/\"/g, "");
    console.log(treatments_value);
    $("#dashboardTreatmentSelector").val(treatments_value);
}
}
```

The value of the parameter is getting printed to the console fine: [1,15].

I can manually type the value from the console into my code and the options are selected:

```
$("#dashboardTreatmentSelector").val([1,15]);
```

If I use the variable, treatments_value...the variable that gets printed to the console, the options don't get selected.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `treatments_value` is a string. Try using `JSON.parse` in `$("#dashboardTreatmentSelector").val()`:

```js
$.urlParam = function(name) {
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard?date_range=ytd&treatments=%5B"1"%2C"15"%5D';
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
  return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}

function setValuesBasedOnParams() {
  var date_range = $.urlParam('date_range');
  var treatments = $.urlParam('treatments');

  if (date_range) {
    $(".btn_dateRangeSelector").removeClass("btn-primary");
    $("#daterange_" + date_range).addClass("btn-primary");
  }
  if (treatments) {
    var t = decodeURIComponent(treatments);
    var treatments_value = t.replace(/\"/g, "");
    console.log(treatments_value);
    $("#dashboardTreatmentSelector").val(JSON.parse(treatments_value));
  }
}

setValuesBasedOnParams();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dashboardTreatmentSelector" class="js-example-basic-multiple- form-control" name="treatments[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option id="1" data-id="1" value="1">dsfrets</option>
  <option id="2" data-id="2" value="2">Aphid Treatment</option>
  <option id="15" data-id="15" value="15">boom pow surprise</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My man! Yes, simple. I forgot to parse the JSON...thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

It might work to remove the `[]` in the name of the select tag (`treatments[]`), as is shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_name.asp), and is even used with the multiple attribute

Answer (score 0):

i think your variable `treatment_values` is of type String instead of being an actual array.

Comment: Yep. I knew it had to be something simple like that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.